# Migrating a CommonJS 'module.exports = function()' to ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs, webex

I am using NodeJS and have been writing JavaScript for a few years now and am still learning.

For my CJS modules, I write (what I call) a root function that contains all of (what I call) my sub-functions and then `return {subfunction1, subfunction2}` on the root function for the functions I wanted to expose. Admittedly, I learned this writing style from [Jonathan Mills](https://app.pluralsight.com/profile/author/jonathan-mills) and have been happy with it.

I am struggling with how to migrate this properly from CommonJS to ESM and am hoping to do so without using a `Class`. However, if `Class` is the right way with ESM, then I will adapt.

Here is a CJS Service:

`service.js`

```js
function WebexService(webex) {
  async function processMessage(messageData) {
    try {
      const user = await webex.people.get(messageData.personId);
      //debug(user);
      sendMessage({ displayName: user.displayName, roomId: messageData.roomId });
    } catch (error) {
      debug(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
  function sendMessage(messageInfo) {
    webex.messages.create({
      roomId: messageInfo.roomId,
      text: `Howdy! ${messageInfo.displayName}`,
    });
  }
  return { processMessage }
}

module.exports = WebexService()
```

To use the this CJS service, I would import it as:

`app.js`

```js
const { processMessage } = require('../services/webexService');

function superCool() {
  const messageResponse = await processMessage(messageData);
}
```

The only way I have been able to get this to work with ESM is as a `Class`:

`service.js`

```js
import debugInit from 'debug';
import chalk from 'chalk';
const debug = debugInit('app:services:webex');

export default class WebexService {
  constructor(webex) {
    this.webex = webex;
  }
  async processMessage(messageData) {
    try {
      const user = await this.webex.people.get(messageData.personId);
      //debug(user);
      this.sendMessage({ displayName: user.displayName, roomId: messageData.roomId });
    } catch (error) {
      debug(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
  sendMessage(messageInfo) {
    this.webex.messages.create({
      roomId: messageInfo.roomId,
      text: `Howdy! ${messageInfo.displayName}`,
    });
  }
}
```

`app.js`

```js
import WebexService from '../services/webex.js';

const WebexServiceInstance = new WebexService(webex);
WebexServiceInstance.processMessage(event.data);
```

I am hopeful someone can point me in the right direction. I'm happy to RTFM if someone can help me find one to read.

Comment: Why does your `WebexService` expect a parameter, but you don't pass anything to it?

Comment: Konrad, Good question as I assume you're referring to the CJS example. For this question, since that is not the focus of my question, it is assumed I am properly initiating it and sending `webex` to the `WebexService`.

Comment: I hope you have mentioned `"type":"module"` in your package.json

Comment: "*I write a root function that contains all of my sub-functions and then `return {subfunction1, subfunction2}` on the root function for the functions I wanted to expose*" - are you calling the root function multiple times or at least in multiple places? If not, this approach seems pretty pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service.js`

```
function WebexService(webex) {
  async function processMessage(messageData) {
    try {
      const user = await webex.people.get(messageData.personId);
      //debug(user);
      sendMessage({ displayName: user.displayName, roomId: messageData.roomId });
    } catch (error) {
      debug(error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
  function sendMessage(messageInfo) {
    webex.messages.create({
      roomId: messageInfo.roomId,
      text: `Howdy! ${messageInfo.displayName}`,
    });
  }
  return { processMessage }
}

const service = WebexService()
export default service
```

`app.js`

```
import WebexService from '../services/webex.js';
// you can then do this
const { processMessage } = WebexService;
function superCool() {
  const messageResponse = await processMessage(messageData);
}
// or just use it directly
function superCool() {
  const messageResponse = await WebexService.processMessage(messageData);
}
```

Comment: Konrad, The above works great. I guess I am a liar though as I thought I had it figured out on how to pass a constructor function `webex` to `WebexService` in ESM. Any ideas on how to pass it?

Comment: I have no idea how you do it in CommonJS, because you call the function without the argument

Comment: In CommJS I would import it into `app.js` as: `const { processMessage } = require('../services/webexService')(webex);`

Comment: `export default WebexService` then `import WebexService from '../services/webex.js';` and `const { processMessage } = WebexService(webex)`

Comment: Thank you Konrad. This is why I like the community at Stack Overflow. I've spent over a week trying to figure this out myself. I appreciate you.